# Updating certain user fields

Tags: go, mgo

Requests to my API contain an ID (required) and optional others fields such as name, email and username.

```
{
    "id" : "12345",
    "name" : "Bob",
    "email" : "test@example.com"
}
```

After binding the request to a struct `user` if there isn't a user with the ID in my database I add them to it using:

```
user.App_id = appId
user.Created_at = (*tools.Timestamp)(&now)
user.Updated_at = (*tools.Timestamp)(&now)
_ = C.Database.C("users").Insert(&user);
```

but if there is a user I only want to update the fields that the request object includes but I'm not sure how to write the query.

My `user` struct uses pointers so that I can check for `nil` values

```
type user struct {
    Id      *string    `bson:"id" json:"id"`
    Name    *string    `bson:"name" json:"name"`
    ...
}
```

An update query that i've used elsewhere in my app looks like this:

```
err := collection("users").Update(bson.M{"id" : "user.Id"},bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"???":"???"}})
```

but I'm not sure how to construct the latter part of the query under these circumstances.

**Note: I'm not using MongoDB's _id**

Comment: How about including the import for your db package? Pretty much required to ask this question.

Comment: What do you mean by import?

Comment: You probably have `import "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"` at the top of your file but how should I know that? Maybe you're using `FictionalMongoDriver` instead. Hard to provide a decent answer when I'm speculating about what library it is you're calling.

Comment: I was hoping the mgo tag at the bottom might help?

Comment: I didn't realize that tag as specifically for the Go mgo driver... I still think it would be smart to include in your question. It's pretty simple to preface your code snippet with relevant imports.

Comment: No worries - but any help with the actual question would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should be able to accomplish this with just

```
err := collection("users").Update(bson.M{"id" : user.Id},bson.M{"$set": &user})
```